# Kentico Update Media Libary Direct Path to Azure

Tags: kentico, kentico-12

We have moved the media stoage to Azure. Any new files successfully get uploaded to Azure and showing the correct URL

[image]

but how do I change the direct path of the old files? I have already uploaded all files to Azure. Just need to know how to update the direct path of the old files.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to either do it manually and change the links of the old direct path URLs or, you can create a script which will check the DB tables and change the URLs. Regrettably, there is no tool or feature to do this available out of the box.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but do you know which database table I need to update? I couldn’t find any DB table with the direct path.

Comment: well, this depends where the links are placed - it could be in page's content - then you need to update the pages tables (https://docs.xperience.io/k12sp/custom-development/working-with-pages-in-the-api/page-database-structure) plus when using workflows, do not forget about the version history tables. Then, maybe you are using media files in some web part or widget properties or other objects - then you need to check given object's DB tables. I do not know your project so I am unable to tell exact DB tables.